# Why use Tomcat's context.xml files to declare DBCP resources?

Tags: tomcat, apache-commons-dbcp, context.xml

I'm having trouble understanding why I would use a context.xml file to declare a resource, in my case a database connection pool. Hopefully I've got my facts straight in the following arguments against using context.xml

1. As far as I can tell, resources
   declared in /META-INF/context.xml
   are only available within the
   context, so there's no reason to do
   so to share resources.
2. Declaring a connection
   pool resource in this way creates a
   dependency on the container's
   classloader, so if I do so and, for example, wish
   to change my database drivers, I
   must restart the container, not just
   my context.
3. I also create a dependency on
   containery things like JNDI, which
   makes standlone testing tricker.
4. Finally, I have to jump through
   build-time hoops to switch resources
   between test and production
   resources for example.

None of these issues are insurmountable, but it certainly seems on paper much more straightforward to just create a connection pool and hook it into my context scope.

I'd like to know under what circumstances are context.xml files the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only valid reason I have seen is if you want Tomcat to be able to use your connection pool for something like it's basic user authentication calls, if you had it setup to do use a JDBC UserAuth context then you may want Tomcat to have connection pooling.

Answer (score 1):

The other reason you might want to use a `context.xml` is to [override servlet init parameters which then maybe used to configure](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters) any number of things including possibly your DBCP managed by something like Spring.

This maybe preferred over system properties and/or environment variables as you can deploy multiple copies of the same WAR in a single container w/o modifying the WAR and their configuration will not overlap.

[By the way the `context.xml` can live outside of the WAR](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) (see Tomcat's documentation on that or a snippet below):

> Individual Context elements may be explicitly defined:
>
> - In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application files. Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML attribute)
>     this may be copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and
>     renamed to application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.
> - In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory. The context
>     path and version will be derived from the base name of the file (the
>     file name less the .xml extension). This file will always take
>     precedence over any context.xml file packaged in the web application's
>     META-INF directory.
> - Inside a Host element in the main conf/server.xml.
>
> Default Context elements may be defined that apply to multiple web
>   applications. Configuration for an individual web application will override anything
>   configured in one of these defaults. Any nested elements, e.g.
>    elements, that are defined in a default Context will be
>   created once for each Context to which the default applies. They will
>   not be shared between Context elements.
>
> - In the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml file: the Context element information will be loaded by all web applications.
> - In the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/context.xml.default file:
>     the Context element information will be loaded by all web applications
>     of that host.